# Difference between *.* and * when used with the cp command and the -R parameter

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I just want to find out what is the difference between

```
cp -R $rootpath/vgcore/core/src/geom/*.* $destpath/geom_src
```

,

```
cp -R $rootpath/vgcore/core/src/geom/* $destpath/geom_src
```

,

```
cp -R $rootpath/vgcore/core/src/geom $destpath/geom_src
```

and

```
cp -R $rootpath/vgcore/core/src/geom/ $destpath/geom_src
```

Let's say we have one subdir in geom, say alg with files in it

1. In the case of one, would only all the files be copied from geom and alg and put into geom_src? So the dir structure of the source will be ignored?
2. all the files from geom and all the files from alg + alg itself will be copied over retaining the subdir structure?
3. sames as 2?
4. sames as 2 & 3?

Sorry, don't have a test Linux machine handy to test this myself.

Thanks.

Comment: `*` will match everything and `*.*` will match anything with a dot in it.  The last two are identical in bahaviour.

Comment: Note that `$rootpath` and `$destpath` need to be quoted -- as `"$rootpath"` and `"$destpath"` -- to behave properly when the names they contain have spaces, characters in IFS, characters which could be evaluated as globs (which can often happen with names containing square brackets), etc. http://shellcheck.net/ will automatically catch this class of errors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question and belongs to either https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux or https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cp -R $rootpath/vgcore/core/src/geom/*.* $destpath/geom_src

Every directory entry (files AND sub directories) with a dot in their name, found in .../src/geom, will be copied to .../geom_src

Note that hidden entries (entries whose name begins with a dot) are not copied because they are not seen.

> cp -R $rootpath/vgcore/core/src/geom/* $destpath/geom_src

This command is the same as above, but more wide - any file (or "directory entry") will be copied, not only those containing a dot in the name.

> cp -R $rootpath/vgcore/core/src/geom $destpath/geom_src
>
> cp -R $rootpath/vgcore/core/src/geom/ $destpath/geom_src

Are equivalent, and different from before. They copy a single object (directory entry) to the destination; single, because no wildcard has been specified. Taking your specific example, these last two commands will copy everything inside .../geom/, more or less same as before, but they will copy once item more, the directory "geom" itself! And all the files that were inside /geom/ will still go under the newly created "geom" in the destination (assuming that it was not yet existing).

If you asked this, then maybe you come from dos or windows. Under dos/winslow, there is no expansion before a command is executed - it is the command itself that interprets the wild cards. Under unix instead, the arguments are expanded beforehand: if you happen to have 200 items in .../src/geom/, the invoked program (cp for example) will receive 200 parameters.

Another dos/unix difference is that dot (* vs *.*) you mention. DOS used file names made by 2 parts separated by a (sometimes invisible) dot. Unix does not, a dot has no particular meaning in a file name, apart from the fact that a name starting with a dot is normally not "seen" (and hence considered) by the shell.

Comment: Appreciate your detailed answer, linuxfan!

Answer (score -1):

When you type anything in bash, what you write is parsed before execution.

One of the pre-execution tasks is the [shell expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) (*File name expansion* in this case).

Now, let's examine your code.

The basic is `cp -R what where` which is  *copy everything starting from `what`, following symbolic links and put it in `where` *.

What differ in your examples is `what`.

The examples 2, 3 and 4, eventually, will make the same thing: copy everything.

The second one will split its work in more than one task; more specifically, one for every folder in `$rootpath/vgcore/core/src/geom`, sequentially;
Eventually you will have all of your folders copied, as in the third and forth commands.

The first example, by the way, is asking for `*.*` which is *everything with at least a dot in it*.

This means that every folder that doesn't have a dot in its name will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation, ingroxd.